# Is there a way to export roles and permissions from marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, roles

I am new to marketing cloud. I am trying to analyse our users' role and permission settings and it is troublesome to capture all settings from all roles pages.

Is there a way to export all roles and permissions from marketing cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to export directly out of the Marketing Cloud UI, but you should be able to accomplish what you need via the *Account User* object available to the SOAP API.

[Account User - SOAP API Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/accountuser.htm)